# Use cucumber-reports.json file to upload to another system

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, cucumber

I am using BDD Cucumber framework written in Java.

As part of the tests, `cucumber-reports.json` file is generated in the target folder. I have to read cucumber-reports.json file and upload it to another system using rest api calls in the Automation framework.
Tests are running using mvn clear verify goal.After hooks are also not working as cucumber-reports.json file is still empty and only gets populated once mvn clear verify goal is completed.

Any suggestions how I can achieve the same?

I have tried adding maven goals as post implementation test.
I am expecting that I should be able to read Cucumber-reports.json file in the code and run the step as a last one which is upload cucumber-reports.json file to another system.

Comment: I have found a solution for this. I will read cucumber_reports.json file as part of the pipeline steps once test execution is completed